# Find sequence limit $x_{n+1} = \frac{3}{4} x_n + \frac{1}{4} \int_0^{|x_n|} f(x) dx$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, analysis

I am doing my Analysis class revision, and here is one of the problem I saw in the past exam papers:

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to [0,1]$ be continuous and $x_0 \in (0,1)$. Define $x_n$ via recurrence:
\begin{equation}
x_{n+1} = \frac{3}{4} x_n^2 + \frac{1}{4}\int_0^{|x_n|}f(x)dx
\end{equation}
Prove that $x_n$ is convergent, and find its limit.

I think it is not hard to show the convergence. Since $f(x) \geq 0$, the integral is non-negative. Hence inductively $x_n \geq 0$ for all $n$. We could drop the absolute value.

Also by induction, $x_n \in (0,1)$, then we have $x_n^2 < x_n$, and we could conclude that $x_n$ is decreasing, because $x_{n+1} \leq \frac{3}{4} x_n + \frac{1}{4} x_n = x_n$.

A decreasing function with a lower bound (i.e, $x_n \geq 0$) is convergent.

However, I am not sure how to find the limit. Usually, if we have a sequence defined by recurrence, we could simply make $x_{n+1} = x_n = x$, and solve for $x$.   However, here we have an integral there, I am wondering if we need to do some estimations and use the Sandwich Theorem.

Comment: It should say $3/4 x_n+1/4 x_n$

Comment: Do you need a factor of $\frac14$ in your statement? Otherwise, when $f(x)$ is identically $1$, then $\{x_n\}$ is actually an increasing sequence.

Comment: Yes thank you! I missed a $\frac{1}{4}$ before the integral.

Comment: $x_{n+1} \le \frac34 x_n^2 + \frac14 x_n = x_n\frac{3x_n+1}{4} \le x_n \frac{3x_0+1}{4}$ because $x_n$ is non-increasing and hence $\le x_0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, after taking the limit, you get that if $\lim x_n=L$, then $0\leq L<1$ and $$L=\frac{3}{4}L^2+\frac{1}{4}\int_0^L f(x) dx$$A similar analysis to what you have done proves that the RHS is less or equal than $L$, and the equality can only happen when $L^2=L$, so $L=0$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I think your point is that, since the RHS is less or equal than $L$, we must have the equality. Then we require that $L^2 = L$ and $\int_0^L f(x) dx = L$. The only possibility is that $L = 0$. Is my understanding correct?